# Arithmetic sequence check my work

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Let $\{a_j\}$ be an arithmetic sequence with the following conditions:

> Given $s_{16} = 376$ and $a_{16} = 46$, find $a_1$.
>
> $$s_n =  \frac{n}{2} \cdot(a_1 + a_n)  $$

$376 = \dfrac{16}{2} \cdot (a_1 + 46)$
$47 - 46 = 1$
$a_1 = 1$

common ratio $= -5$?

Don't need that value however.

Comment: $a_1$ is correct, $d=5$. What was the question in this exercise?

Comment: It was to find a1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but it would be better to write it something like $$376=\frac {16}2(a_1+46)\\\frac {376}8=a_1+46\\1=a_1$$
Your statement that $47-46=1$ is correct, but is not motivated.  This is why we keep the variables in the equations.

The difference (not common ratio) is $5$, not $-5$ as the terms are increasing.

Comment: Thank you for the help and I agree.

Answer (score 1):

After $376 = \dfrac{16}{2} \cdot (a_1 + 46)$ you get, $a_1+ 46=376\times \frac{2}{16}$ or, $a_1=47-46=1$ so finally you get $a_1=1$.